# WebSVN - Authentication for paths in the repository

Tags: svn, authentication, websvn

I need simple 'to-the-point' tutorial or neat exemple of How to implement authorization for paths (checkout diretories) out of a single Subversion repository, using WebSVN.

Lets say repository is /svn/repos/r_project
Two checkout (paths) from this repos are /svn/repos/path1 and /svn/repos/path2 ...
I want to protect each path (directory) with a different username/password.

Subversion and WebSVN are installed on Unix Apache (redhat). Already i can see the two paths in the WebSVN repository front page - without any protection this is working fine.

I know how to protect individual web index page with .htpasswd but anything i have tried to protect individual paths in the repository through WebSVN page has failed.

Tx

[EDIT nov26]

Up to date situation to make it clear:
Paths i have:

```
Home path in unix: '/var/www/'
Path of WebSVN: '/var/www/websvn2'
Path to repository: '/svn/repos'
Created repository is '/svn/repos/r_project') // so r_project is the repository name 
Two checkout directories of that repository:'/svn/repos/path1' and '/svn/repos/path2'
```

In **httpd.conf** i have locations for SVN and WEBSVN (i do have the necessary modules):

```
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /websvn210/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    Require valid-user
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-file
</Location>
```

For now, 'svn-auth-file' contains password for one user name. Put in '/etc' directory.

In **config.php** file of WebSVN i have:

```
$config->parentPath("/var/www/svn/repos");  
$config->useAuthenticationFile('/etc/svn-auth-file'); // Global access file
```

---

I'm able to see checkout directories 'path1' and 'path2' as regular index page with files in the browser (ex: 'http://mydomain/svn/repos/path1'). However, when i go for 'http://mydomain/websvn210' in the browser i only get the login (ok) than an empty home page of WebSVN - that is, no repository or checkout paths!

That's first problem: empty page.
Second, will be to have different login for each path.
Note: those paths (checkouts) are only for reading or downloading (no commit done from Subversion).

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for '*authz*'. This is one of the many [tutorials](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2006/03/03/access-control-for-subversion-with-apache2-and-authz/) available.

**EDIT**
I think you're mixing two things together which do not belong together. One way to access a subversion repository is via WebDAV, this seems to be working. WebSVN on the other hand is for repository *browsing*. You won't be able to commit changes to your WebSVN URL.

Your 'SVNParentPath' should point to the repository and not to the WebSVN directory.

```
SVNParentPath /svn/repos
```

Comment: Thank. I hahe Subversion installed and working fine. My problem is with WebSVN. I have followed all instructions given but just cannot see the repository (and paths) on the websvn page.

Comment: I know ... its not a very funny question to answer and Stackoverflow may be not the best place to expose such a problem. I will try to find a forum devoted to subversion and websvn. thanks.

Comment: @volvox: post your configuration files. Your comment is contrary to your question. Is websvn working with your configuration and you just want an authentication layer on top.

Comment: OK - i will edit my QUESTION with up to date configuration file i have and problem. Tx.

Comment: "WebSVN on the other hand is for repository browsing. You won't be able to commit changes to your WebSVN URL." ... I am aware of that. Concerning the 'SVNParentPath' , i"m already pointing to the repository parent path - no ? (/svn/repos)

Comment: @volvox: Possibly not. There is a difference between relative './svn' and absolute '/svn' paths. It might be a security risk to use apache's DocumentRoot for your svn repositories.

Comment: In any case, i'm running after my tail. No two tutorials are the same, everyone make me change the parameters, paths, etc. with no result - the paths never show under websvn. I'm spending more time fixing subversion\websvn then my real project!! Tx.

Comment: @volvox: see http://serverfault.com/questions/13853/how-do-i-restrict-repository-access-via-websvn/13912#13912 as template.

Comment: @zellus ... thanks. The link helped me a bit. So, i was able to fix the connection to websvn with password removing this line from my config.php file: '$config->useAuthenticationFile('/etc/svn-auth-file'); // Global access file' This may be not usual but it works in may case.