# WebSVN different login for different repos

Tags: svn, websvn

Can some one tell me how to do I enable LOGIN function for WebSVN for different users but allow the main WebSVN page to be visible showing all the different repos available.

I was tasked to create a SVN for my team, and the following is one of the links I followed which helped me successfully setup my first repos.

https://websvnphp.github.io/docs/install.html

But after installing WebSVN, i can see my repos but any valid user can access all repos.

If my users access the repos directly (http://example.com/repos/repo1) they get access if auth for that repo.

my httpd.conf content:

```
DAV svn 
SVNParentPath /home/svn2 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Subversion repository" 
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd 
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz 
Require valid-user
```

my authz content:

```
[repos:/] 
janedoe = r
```

This question is the closest I have found, but still want main WebSVN page to show all repos and when selecting one to view, prompt for auth on that repo.

[WebSVN - Authentication for paths in the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280034/websvn-authentication-for-paths-in-the-repository)